# How to access IDWriteLocalFontFileLoader method in c#

Tags: c#, interface, directx, directwrite

im using DirectN in my project, everything else works fine, i can use DWriteFunctions class to create a factory, except i can't find a class to access IDWriteLocalFontFileLoader interface to use the method inside. i googled a lot but i just don't know how to do that

Comment: IDWriteFactory::CreateFontFileReference(localpath, ...) will get you a IDWriteFontFile, and from this you can call IDWriteFontFile::GetLoader that you should be able to cast into a IDWriteLocalFontFileLoader since it was loaded with a local font file (if the file pointed by the path exists).

Comment: Microsoft has a code sample that illustrates an implementation for your scenario: https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-classic-samples/tree/main/Samples/DirectWriteCustomFontSets

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this:

- get an [IDWriteFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritefactory) using [DWriteCreateFactory function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nf-dwrite-dwritecreatefactory) .
- call [IDWriteFactory::CreateFontFileReference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nf-dwrite-idwritefactory-createfontfilereference) with a font localpath `CreateFontFileReference(localpath, ...)`. This will get you a [IDWriteFontFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritefontfile) reference.
- call [IDWriteFontFile::GetLoader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nf-dwrite-idwritefontfile-getloader) this will get you a [IDWriteFontFileLoader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritefontfileloader) reference.
- QueryInterface that reference for a [IDWriteLocalFontFileLoader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritelocalfontfileloader). It should world since it was loaded from a local font file. The file pointed by the path must exists.

Comment: Don't cast it directly to [IDWriteLocalFontFileLoader](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritelocalfontfileloader). Use [QueryInterface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/unknwn/nf-unknwn-iunknown-queryinterface(refiid_void)). On Windows 10 or more, it can fails when the font isn't local. See [DWRITE_LOCALITY](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite_3/ne-dwrite_3-dwrite_locality)

Comment: @jeremiebergeron - yes, that's what I meant, thanks